# How to create HashSet from List<Object> by taking multiple field values from object with Java8 Stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

DataHistoryRecord class:

```
public class DataHistoryRecord {

Long dataCreatedBy;
Long dataModifiedBy;
getters & setters

}
```

I have `List<DataHistoryRecord>` and i want to create `HashSet` from it with unique `dataCreatedBy` and `dataModifiedBy` id.

For example : If list has following two records:

DataHistoryRecord1 with dataCreatedBy: 1 and dataModifiedBy: 2

DataHistoryRecord2 with dataCreatedBy: 1 and dataModifiedBy: 3

Output `HashSet` should have three values; 1,2,3

**Note : Please suggest approach without foreach**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
Set<Long> uniqueValues = historyRecords.stream()
        .flatMap(hr -> Stream.of(hr.getCreatedBy(), hr.getModifiedBy()))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Hint if OP really needs `HashSet`: `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new))` - Since for `Collectors.toSet()` "There are no guarantees on the type ... of the Set returned;" ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet()))

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
      Set<Long> collect = list
         .stream()
         .flatMap(record -> Stream.of(record.getCreatedBy(), record.getModifiedBy())
         .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: @S.K. Should we use foreach or the approach you suggested? which one is better, any idea?